# SDL Android: Exiting an application and issue with colours

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, sdl

My misadventures in Android continue, and altho it seems silly to ask about everything, I haven't had any luck with trial-and-error or even Google.

I am using C++ native SDL program in android via NDK.

So first things first: I can't get as simple thing as exiting an application to work. I have fiddled hours with SDLActivity.java and the cpp but nothing seems to work. I mean exiting a program, not just minimizing the process. I know it's not advised but I would like to implement it to some of my programs.
I have tried, according to stuff found online:

```
System.exit() in SDLActivity
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid() ); in SDLActivity
System.finish() in SDLActivity
System.exit(0);
```

But nothing works, they all just minimize the process but it's still running and continues from the moment of exit when returning

The second thing is about colors. All colors I'm drawing are off when the app is running normally but they appear what they should be when something system messages or the volume dialog appears and then return to the distorted form when it disappears. Is this because perhaps I'm having wrong pixel format for the window? I'm not initializing it to anything specific.